# JLabels at the edge of the GUI Java

Tags: java, user-interface

I have some labels added to west of my GUI screen,
the labels are hanging right on the bounds of the GUI, and I was wondering if there was a way to bring the labels in a bit so that the words don't start right on the edge of the western end of the gui bounds...

Comment: Which labels which UI. Please post minimal working code that could explain more

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Assuming* you are using swing, you could take a look at the [`BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(int top, int left, int bottom, int right)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/BorderFactory.html#createEmptyBorder%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) factory, such as below (taken from [here](http://www.andrels.com/wp-en_US/2009/08/inserting-padding-into-a-jlabel/)):

```
JLabel jLabel = new JLabel("My JLabel");
//Border used as padding
Border paddingBorder = BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10,10,10,10);

jLabel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(border,paddingBorder));
```